# Kotlin and ObjectBox: Relations in Data Classes

Tags: android, objectbox

How can I initialize a Data Class with a ToOne relation? For example, I have the two Data Classes below:

```
@Entity
data class EntityA(
    @Id var id: Long,
    var entityB: ToOne<EntityB>
)

@Entity
data class EntityB(
    @Id var id: Long
)
```

Now, I want to initialize EntityA like that:

```
var e = EntityA(1, EntityB())
```

But, obviously, I can't do that because the second argument is a ToOne and not an EntityB. I tried to instantiate ToOne but its constructor wants a second argument that I don't know how to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not put the relation in the primary constructor. Then you can use a secondary constructor to call `toOne.target = entity`. It should look like something like this:

```
@Entity
data class EntityA(@Id var id: Long) {
    lateinit var entityB: ToOne<EntityB>

    constructor(b: EntityB) : this(0) {
        entityB.target = b
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I make this work with data classes that are deserialized from json? I have a json, with a list of values for one of it's properties, I deserialize that property to `List<Foo>`, and I want to use the same property as `OneToMany` in ObjectBox. Is this possible? If not, is there an elegant workaround?